# Windows: remove() fails with error access denied ( error code 5) despite of no open handle in current process or other processes

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Environment**

Windows 7, Windows 2008 server
C++ program run in multithreading.

**Scenario**

In multithreading, we extract several files from archive containers to user defined temp directory ( say c:\temp) and delete them after processing.
But some of the files are unable to delete with error access denied.
We are using remove() API for deleting files.

**Observations**

1. This is observed in Multithreading environment only.
2. Confirmed that each temp file is getting processed in SINGLE thread only and that thread is thread closing it before attempting to delete it.
3. No handle leak is seen after running test, but some files are remaining in our temp dir.
4. Issue is not consistently reproducible. (Gets reproduced in 1/3 attempts). Each time different files are remaining in temp dir.
5. There is no permission issue as well, that means files are not read only.
6. Confirmed that no other processes like AntiVirus, Windows Search indexer is running.         - After putting breakpoint, we can manually delete file
7. After calling handles.exe on culprit file (inside code as child process) immediately after remove failure, it output is "No matching handles found"

**Workaround**

Reattempting remove after 10 miliseconds is WORKING.

Instead of workaround, we are looking for proper fix, but we are unable to figure out why we are unable to remove such temp file despite of no open handles in any process?

Comment: Post the code. Are you sure that you closing the file handle ?

Comment: Maybe your virus scanner is scanning the files?

Comment: The *same* thread first closes a file, then attempts to delete it, right?